Mesh converted to volume looses stored attribute, how to shade it?

Hi,
I have a piece of geometry that I made by extruding a spline (Bezier + 'Curve to Mesh' with a rectangular profile) in Geometry Nodes.
I convert it to a Volume. and now I'd like to apply a gradient to the Emission slot in the Volume.
Im using an attribute caught before extruding. That attribute doesn't work when the geometry is coverted to a volume.
Is there a way to make it work somehow?

This is not currently possible 'as is' for geometry nodes. There are a number of nodes in experimental development  for storing / sampling from volumes, but currently when a mesh is converted to a volume you can't then store additional data on the volume.

I see. Hope this will be possible one day :) Thanks for confirming this @bunchofbradys !
Have a good one.
